# Firebase realtime db multipath update fails

Tags: node.js, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-functions

I'm trying to perform a multipath update on a firebase realtime db using a cloud function (js sdk). Update parameters are constructed through a `forEach` loop. The update fails with following error message :
`Error: Reference.update failed: First argument  must be an object containing the children to replace.`

I might be close to the solution considering the console.log :

`[{"-LfzkTClUxC9J5y3Ue95/mood/sun":{"value":-75,"votecount":-1},"-LfzkTClUxC9J5y3Ue95/mood/rain":{"value":"7550","votecount":1}},
...
{"-LfzoAT7fPzhWsMpEU7t/mood/sun":{"value":0,"votecount":-1},"-LfzoAT7fPzhWsMpEU7t/mood/rain":{"value":"050","votecount":1}}]`.

This is my cloud function :

```
exports.updateGroupMood = functions.database.ref('users/{userId}/mood/')
.onUpdate((change, context) => {

const userId = context.params.userId //previous data
const beforeData = change.before.val()  //current data
const afterData = change.after.val()  
const userGroups = admin.database().ref('/users/' + userId +       
'/groups/social/Items'); //user groups to update

return userGroups.once("value")
.then(function(snapshot) {

var updateParams = []

snapshot.forEach(function(childSnapshot){

  const itemId = childSnapshot.key //id of group to update
  const moodRef = admin.database().ref('/groups/social/Items/' + itemId + '/mood/'); //node to update

  var promise = moodRef.once("value").then(function(snapshot) { //get values to update

    const objVal = snapshot.val()

    const previousMood = { // decrement previous values
      value:objVal[beforeData.element].value - beforeData.value,
      votecount:objVal[beforeData.element].votecount - 1,
    }
    const currentMood = { // increment new values
      value:objVal[afterData.element].value + afterData.value,
      votecount: objVal[afterData.element].votecount + 1,
    }  

    const newMood = { // update params definition
      [itemId + '/mood/' + beforeData.element]: previousMood,
      [itemId + '/mood/' + afterData.element]: currentMood,
    }
    return newMood

  });
  // construct update params
  updateParams.push(promise);

});
//get update params
return Promise.all(updateParams);
}).then(function(values) {

console.log(JSON.stringify(values)); //cf console.log in text above

const updateObj = admin.database().ref('/groups/social/Items/')

//update nodes
updateObj.update(JSON.stringify(values))   
})
})
```

Answer (score 0):

You're passing in a JSON string of the updates, while you should actually be passing in the updates:

```
updateObj.update(values)
```

Comment: Thanks Frank, but when I pass in plain updates as mentionned by you, I get following error :    Error: Reference.update failed: First argument  contains an invalid key (-LfzkTClUxC9J5y3Ue95/mood/rain) in property 'groups.social.Items.0'.  Keys must be non-empty strings and can't contain ".", "#", "$", "/", "[", or "]"

[2019-05-30T11:24:03.594Z]  @firebase/database: FIREBASE WARNING: Passing an Array to Firebase.update() is deprecated. Use set() if you want to overwrite the existing data, or an Object with integer keys if you really do want to only update some of the children.

Comment: console.log for values is as follows : [ { '-LfzkTClUxC9J5y3Ue95/mood/sun': { value: 125, votecount: 1 } },
  { '-LfzoAT7fPzhWsMpEU7t/mood/sun': { value: 200, votecount: 1 } },
  { '-Lfzoe1kYFzWJ8IabD89/mood/sun': { value: 350, votecount: 6 } }
...
  { '-LfzotZTvmRwoP7UdV9d/mood/sun': { value: 350, votecount: 6 } } ]

Comment: I don't immediately see what's wrong with that, but am certain that using `JSON.stringify()` on it is not the solution. Can you reproduce the problem with just a single hard-coded value for `values`?

Comment: I found what's directly causing the problem : values object needs to be flattened first. When I hardcode     `[ { '-LfzkTClUxC9J5y3Ue95/mood/sun': { value: 125, votecount: 1 } }]` it throws an error. On the other hand `{'-LfzkTClUxC9J5y3Ue95/mood/sun': { value: 125, votecount: 1}}` works fine. So I went with a workarround as follows :

Comment: `var a = JSON.stringify(values)
    var b = a.replace("[","")
    var c = b.replace("]","")
    var d = c.replace(/}},/g,"},")
    var e = d.replace(/,{/g,",")
    var f = JSON.parse(e)
    const updateObj = admin.database().ref('/groups/social/Items/')
    //update nodes
    updateObj.update(f)`
This workaround executes fast enough for my needs (60ms for 250 ItemIds). But I hate it since I do not address the root cause of the problem. Any Ideas?